# Copyright information in the header of a source file

Tags: open-source, licensing

I want to open source some code. What should I write in the header of files? Just copyright statements or the license text? Should other parties add their copyright statements to the header, if they contribute to the project?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 2):

> What should I write in the header of files?

That depends on many things like the license(s) that apply to the file, the authors and their requirements.

I would start writing on top of the file of which software that file is part of. Like the name of the software. Do you have a name?

> Just copyright statements or the license text?

You are more or less free to choose. It's common top keep headers short, so you normally don't put the full license text into each source file. Instead it is common to put it into a file called `LICENSE` inside the projects root-dir.

> Should other parties add their copyright statements to the header, if they contribute to the project?

If they do contributions that fall under copyright they might want to, however, there is no need to place an actual copyright line to have it copyrighted. That is not needed (any longer under Berne Convention - somehwere sometime it once was).

To document authorship, signed patches are a much better way to keep track of things. A modern source code version control system makes this easy.

However you might want to give credits somewhere, so you can keep an `AUTHORS` and `CONTRIBUTORS` file if you wish. Think about how you want to handle that in your project and offer the information upfront so contributors know how you have intended to do such things.